# Push value into array in D

Tags: arrays, push, d

Is there any D's native function (like `push()` or so on) to put a value into a dynamic array or should I write myself (a bit tedious) function to every class like:

```
void push(myarr x)
{
   myarr[myarr.length++] = x
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use the concat operator `~`:

```
void push(T)(ref T[] myarr, T x)
{
   myarr~=x
}
```

Comment: Is there's no equivalent in the D standard?

Comment: Technically, that's the append operator (`~` concatenates, `~=` appends), but it's the right thing to use. There's no need to add any function to do this, because it's a built-in operator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. D has the array concatenation operators `~` and `~=`.

Example:

```
int[] arr = [ 3, 2 ];
arr ~= 0;
std.stdio.writeln(arr); 

// Prints: [3, 2, 0]
```

More about this: [D Language Reference, Array Concatenation](http://dlang.org/arrays.html#array-concatenation).

If you want your own type to use these operators, you will have to [overload op assignment operators](http://dlang.org/operatoroverloading.html#OpAssign).